# How to validate when THREE checkboxes checked in YUP?

Tags: formik, yup

I have three checkboxes:

```
[*] option one
[*] option two
[*] option three
```

Valid state is only when all THREE are checked.
All other states are not valid and should display error message.

How to implement it with yup?

My current implementation that doesn't work. It only validates single checkbox, not all.

```
yup.object().shape({
  registerTerms: yup.boolean().oneOf([true], 'Must Accept Terms of Service'),
  registerCookie: yup.boolean().oneOf([true], 'Must Accept Cookie Policy'),
  registerPrivacy: yup.boolean().oneOf([true], 'Must Accept Privacy Policy'),
}),
```

Answer (score 3):

Your schema definition looks correct.

```
import * as yup from "yup";

const schema = yup.object().shape({
  registerTerms: yup.boolean().oneOf([true], "Must Accept Terms of Service"),
  registerCookie: yup.boolean().oneOf([true], "Must Accept Cookie Policy"),
  registerPrivacy: yup.boolean().oneOf([true], "Must Accept Privacy Policy")
});

const validInputObj = {
  registerTerms: true,
  registerCookie: true,
  registerPrivacy: true
};

const invalidInputObj = {
  registerTerms: true,
  registerCookie: true,
  registerPrivacy: false
};

schema.isValid(validInputObj).then(isValid => console.log(isValid));   // true
schema.isValid(invalidInputObj).then(isValid => console.log(isValid)); // false
```

I've [tested it out in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/93p6258kl4) and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: How would i do it if i need only one of the three?